# Disadvantages of nested synchronized blocks

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, synchronized

Learning about threads and concurrency. Consider the following code:

```
class A {

  protected final Object lock = new Object();

  public void remove(Object obj){
    synchronized(lock){
      // remove the object
    }
  }

  public void add(Object obj){
    synchronized(lock){
      // add the object
    }
  }
}
```

This code is thread-safe in the sense that no two different threads can `add` or `remove` while one thread is in the process of adding or removing.

Now consider the following sublcass of A:

```
class B extends A {

  public void update1(Object original, Object newObj){
    remove(original);
    add(original); 
  }

  public void update2(Object original, Object newObj){
    synchronized(lock) {
      remove(original);
      add(newObj);
    }
  }

}
```

Class `B` must implement a thread-safe `update` method. Now, as far as I know `update1` is not thread safe because the operation is not atomic, i.e. there is no synchronization between the execution of `remove` and `add` (correct me if wrong).

Is `update2` the correct way to implement a thread-safe `update` method?
Are there any disadvantages of having nested synchronized blocks over the same `lock`?

Comment: I think this kind of code is fraught with deadlock peril.  You'd be better off using the more modern additions to the JVM: concurrent package, ExcecutorService, and parallelStream if you're up to JDK 8.

Comment: Both `update1` and `update2` are thread safe. Having `synchronized(lock)` in `update2` is superfluous because you have already set up the syncronization in class A methods. Once a thread acuired a lock, it can goes through all following `synchronize` block without needing to re acquire it.

Comment: @ortis I think they want the remove and add to be done transactionally. In `update1`, another thread may remove or add between the invocations.

Comment: @duffymo The same lock object is used in both cases, so this should not cause a deadlock.

Comment: That I would not do.  My original advice still stands.  Dealing with multithreaded code is hard for smart people.

Comment: @duffymo, use ExecutorService instead of what?  The examples don't show any threads being created, they only show methods that may be called _in_ threads.  ExecutorService is just a higher-level abstraction for getting your code to run in multiple threads.

Comment: What does ExecutorService run?  (Hint: Runnable).  You should write your Runnable without synchronization.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is `update2` the correct way to implement a thread-safe update method?

Yes, it is. You have achieved atomicity and you are compatible with callers of the individual `add` and `remove` methods.

> Are there any disadvantages of having nested synchronized blocks over the same lock?

No, because the locks are *reentrant*, meaning the second acquisition doesn't do anything more than remember that the lock was acquired once more, so it doesn't get released until two *release* actions are performed.

Answer (score 0):

The lock is re entrant unless you would be seeing deadlocks every where

Re-entrant lock is the lock which can be reaquired even if the lock is already attained by the same thread.

Why wont you provide the removeAndAdd in the Super class  method if there is a scenario which must have remove and add atomic .

Make sure your lock object is marked private and final for security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

The use of `synchronized` makes the whole object "locked": no other threads can call any methods while another thread is running one of the object synchronized methods.

This behavior can really slow some program.

As an alternative, you can use [`ReentrantLock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html).

Here is how it applies for the code in the post:

```
class A {
  protected final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

  public void remove(Object obj){
    lock.lock();
    try {
      // remove the object
    } finally {
       lock.unlock();
    }
  }

  public void add(Object obj){
    lock.lock();
    try {
      // add the object
    } finally {
       lock.unlock();
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  // ...

  public void update2(Object original, Object newObj){
     lock.lock();
     try {
        remove(original);
        add(newObj);
     } finally {
       lock.unlock();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Calling a `synchronized` method does not "lock" an object.  It only prevents other threads from synchronizing on the same object at the same time.  Your example uses different means to achieve _exactly_ the same result as @fernandohur 's example.